# Why my STL sort is not sorting the vector of strings?

Tags: c++, sorting

If I use the following STL sort then it is not sorting the strings. Can anyone please tell why?

```
vector<vector<string>>& favs;
for (auto comps : favs)
    sort(comps.begin(), comps.end());
```

Comment: `auto& comps`? Typo....

Comment: `auto comps` makes a copy so your sort operates on the copy.